# Center responsive div with unknown height and enable full vertical scroll

Tags: css, responsive-design, centering

I'm trying to center a div with an unknown height.

I can't find a solution that allows scroll to the top of the div when the viewport height is less than the div height.

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>This will be hidden when <br />
  window_height < div_width</p>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
 How to make it scroll to the top?
</div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
      background: grey;
    }
    p{
      background: green;
    }
    div {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      max-width: 500px;
      width:100%;
      height: 700px; /* Unknown*/
      padding: 20px;  
      background: red;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

http://codepen.io/Koopa/pen/GpypdX

Thanks

Comment: "I can't find a solution that allows to scroll to the top when the viewport_height < div_height".... what do you mean by scroll?  You want javascript to scroll the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you can't scroll to the top of the `div` is because the `transform` property with negative values positions the `div` off-screen on smaller screens.

In this demo `transform` is disabled:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKpMyM

Also, when you apply absolute positioning to an element you take it out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos) of the document. This means it is ignored by its container. Hence, the `body` and `html` element have zero height.

In this demo the `body` has a green border (which is totally collapsed):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWxrod

To make your layout work, you can give the `body` a minimum height (so it can expand along with the `div`) and, instead of centering with absolute positioning, use a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

**CSS**

```
html { height: 100%; } /* necessary for percentage heights to work */

body {
    background: grey;
    border: 10px solid green; /* for demo purposes */
    min-height: 100%; /* allow body to expand with children */
    display: flex; /* establish flex container */
    justify-content: center; /* center div horizontally, in this case */
    align-items: center; /* center div vertically, in this case */
}

p {
  background: green;
}

div {
    /* REMOVE
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */

    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 500px;
    width:100%;
    height: 700px; /* Unknown*/
    padding: 20px;  
    background: red;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyzMvV

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*

Comment: I actually wanted to stay away from flex-box because of browser support, however I will drop IE9 now. flex-box is far too useful ;)  Thanks for your answer